# Android S8+ warning message "does not support the current Display size setting and may behave unexpectedly"

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat, samsung-s8

I have this warning message in Samsung S8+ Android 7:

> APP_NAME does not support the current Display size setting and may
>   behave unexpectedly.

What it means and how can I remove it?

Thank you

Comment: Check this:   http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1351395/android-os-message-on-app-start.html

Comment: I have seen this post in Unity3d but do not resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding in `supports-screens`

> android:xlargeScreens="true"

and removing:

> android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"

Answer (score 0):

So you need to create different folders and maintain all xml in those folders.

The following is a list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for medium, high, and extra high density screens.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

For more info see this link
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

and for S8+ u can  Extra large