# Application does not support the current display size

Tags: java, android

I am working with new Android application. It works fine with different devices, but I tried to use it with Note 5 (API 24) Android 7.0 and received this error:

> does not support the current Display size setting and may behave
>   unexpectedly

this is my gradle:

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ahmad.kedmatii"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

and here is my mainifest :

```
  <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

So what should I do to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that [this is an warning message specific to some Samsung devices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46361871/154306). The answer there suggests **removing** the following line from your manifest:

```
android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
```

Additionally, another issue you might face has to do with aspect ratios. You can add support for additional aspect ratios as follows:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
```

By *not* supporting long aspect ratios, your app will appear with black bars to ensure that it fits well on the screen. This may be preferred over adapting the layout for a small set of devices, but that decision is up to you.

[See this answer for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628047/how-to-support-189-aspect-ratio-in-android-apps)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding in supports-screens

```
android:xlargeScreens="true"
```

and removing:

```
android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
```

for more [help](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html)

Hope this help you

Comment: I will try and tell you

Answer (score -1):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "naveen.naveen.sendsms"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```